Why can't Prometheus correctly identify this data?
I used Prometheus to collect this data, but it prompted an error "expected label name, got "\n" ("INVALID") while parsing: "{\n" ".
# HELP disk_free_bytes Usable space for path
# TYPE disk_free_bytes gauge
disk_free_bytes{path="/smore-safe/.",} 7.63017232384E11
  # HELP tomcat_sessions_created_sessions_total  
  # TYPE tomcat_sessions_created_sessions_total counter
tomcat_sessions_created_sessions_total 0.0
  # HELP executor_pool_max_threads The maximum allowed number of threads in the pool
  # TYPE executor_pool_max_threads gauge
executor_pool_max_threads{name="applicationTaskExecutor",} 2.147483647E9
  # HELP jvm_gc_pause_seconds Time spent in GC pause
  # TYPE jvm_gc_pause_seconds summary
jvm_gc_pause_seconds_count{action="end of major GC",cause="Metadata GC Threshold",} 1.0
jvm_gc_pause_seconds_sum{action="end of major GC",cause="Metadata GC Threshold",} 0.254
jvm_gc_pause_seconds_count{action="end of minor GC",cause="Allocation Failure",} 50.0
jvm_gc_pause_seconds_sum{action="end of minor GC",cause="Allocation Failure",} 2.605
  # HELP jvm_gc_pause_seconds_max Time spent in GC pause
  # TYPE jvm_gc_pause_seconds_max gauge
jvm_gc_pause_seconds_max{action="end of major GC",cause="Metadata GC Threshold",} 0.0
jvm_gc_pause_seconds_max{action="end of minor GC",cause="Allocation Failure",} 0.0
  # HELP jvm_memory_usage_after_gc_percent The percentage of long-lived heap pool used after the last GC event, in the range [0..1]
  # TYPE jvm_memory_usage_after_gc_percent gauge
jvm_memory_usage_after_gc_percent{area="heap",pool="long-lived",} 0.3453918753182791
  # HELP process_uptime_seconds The uptime of the Java virtual machine
  # TYPE process_uptime_seconds gauge
process_uptime_seconds 13187.364
  # HELP executor_completed_tasks_total The approximate total number of tasks that have completed execution
  # TYPE executor_completed_tasks_total counter
executor_completed_tasks_total{name="applicationTaskExecutor",} 0.0
  # HELP tomcat_sessions_expired_sessions_total  
  # TYPE tomcat_sessions_expired_sessions_total counter
tomcat_sessions_expired_sessions_total 0.0
  # HELP process_start_time_seconds Start time of the process since unix epoch.
  # TYPE process_start_time_seconds gauge
process_start_time_seconds 1.732159846302E9
  # HELP disk_total_bytes Total space for path
  # TYPE disk_total_bytes gauge
disk_total_bytes{path="/smore-safe/.",} 9.38932719616E11
  # HELP system_cpu_usage The "recent cpu usage" of the system the application is running in
  # TYPE system_cpu_usage gauge
system_cpu_usage 0.15040745873605949
  # HELP jvm_threads_daemon_threads The current number of live daemon threads
  # TYPE jvm_threads_daemon_threads gauge
jvm_threads_daemon_threads 38.0
  # HELP tomcat_sessions_active_max_sessions  
  # TYPE tomcat_sessions_active_max_sessions gauge
tomcat_sessions_active_max_sessions 0.0
  # HELP tomcat_sessions_rejected_sessions_total  
  # TYPE tomcat_sessions_rejected_sessions_total counter
tomcat_sessions_rejected_sessions_total 0.0
  # HELP jvm_threads_peak_threads The peak live thread count since the Java virtual machine started or peak was reset
  # TYPE jvm_threads_peak_threads gauge
jvm_threads_peak_threads 148.0
  # HELP jvm_memory_committed_bytes The amount of memory in bytes that is committed for the Java virtual machine to use
  # TYPE jvm_memory_committed_bytes gauge
jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="heap",id="Tenured Gen",} 7.15849728E8
jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="heap",id="Eden Space",} 2.86326784E8
jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="nonheap",id="Metaspace",} 1.57376512E8
jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="nonheap",id="Code Cache",} 7.1827456E7
jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="heap",id="Survivor Space",} 3.5782656E7
jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="nonheap",id="Compressed Class Space",} 1.9267584E7
  # HELP jvm_gc_memory_promoted_bytes_total Count of positive increases in the size of the old generation memory pool before GC to after GC
  # TYPE jvm_gc_memory_promoted_bytes_total counter
jvm_gc_memory_promoted_bytes_total 2.06701096E8
  # HELP spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max  
  # TYPE spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max gauge
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="saveAll",repository="TagRecordRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="statisticalTodayLevel",repository="EventRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="findUwbElectronRegion",repository="ElectronRegionRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.004595823
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="EventRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="countByFloorIdAndShowFence",repository="ElectronRegionRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="FloorRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="findAllByIds",repository="DetectionRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.001629891
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="findByRoleIdsAndTypeNot",repository="MenuRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="deleteById",repository="SubscribeRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="findById",repository="DetectionRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="findByUserId",repository="RoleRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="ElectronDetectionRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="LockerRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="latestFirstAlarmsOf3",repository="EventRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="fetchPendingVideo",repository="VideoRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.107953707
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="fetchFailVideo",repository="VideoRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.080533529
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="DetectionRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="PersonnelRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="RoleRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="TenantDatabaseRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.00137626
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="latestAlarmsOf20",repository="EventRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="TagRecordRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="EquipmentRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.008864772
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="findAllByPageable",repository="SubscribeRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="findById",repository="EquipmentRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="updateLocation",repository="EquipmentRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="ElectronRegionRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="MenuRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="UserRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="findByUsername",repository="UserRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="findWithFloor",repository="EquipmentRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="LabEquipmentTrackCoordinateRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="TrackCoordinateRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="save",repository="EquipmentRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="findById",repository="TenantRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="save",repository="EquipmentDeployRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="findById",repository="RoleRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="findByAreaId",repository="EquipmentRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="save",repository="DetectionRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="AreaRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="LabEquipmentRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="findByType",repository="DetectionRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="findByRoleId",repository="UserRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="save",repository="RoleRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="deleteById",repository="PersonnelRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="findByIsPauseIsFalse",repository="QuartzJobRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{exception="None",method="save",repository="LogRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.0
  # HELP spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds  
  # TYPE spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds summary
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="saveAll",repository="TagRecordRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 1.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="saveAll",repository="TagRecordRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.085199293
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="statisticalTodayLevel",repository="EventRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 10.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="statisticalTodayLevel",repository="EventRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.755629392
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="findUwbElectronRegion",repository="ElectronRegionRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 2643.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="findUwbElectronRegion",repository="ElectronRegionRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 9.547612391
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="EventRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 32.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="EventRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 7.355775973
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="countByFloorIdAndShowFence",repository="ElectronRegionRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 27.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="countByFloorIdAndShowFence",repository="ElectronRegionRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.070844169
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="FloorRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 27.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="FloorRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.043744701
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="findAllByIds",repository="DetectionRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 9212.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="findAllByIds",repository="DetectionRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 7.037832562
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="findByRoleIdsAndTypeNot",repository="MenuRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 4.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="findByRoleIdsAndTypeNot",repository="MenuRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.013777451
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="deleteById",repository="SubscribeRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 1.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="deleteById",repository="SubscribeRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.013856348
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="findById",repository="DetectionRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 1.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="findById",repository="DetectionRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.001868603
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="findByUserId",repository="RoleRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 48.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="findByUserId",repository="RoleRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.120967182
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="ElectronDetectionRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 27.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="ElectronDetectionRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.039952503
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="LockerRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 6.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="LockerRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.01559135
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="latestFirstAlarmsOf3",repository="EventRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 10.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="latestFirstAlarmsOf3",repository="EventRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.999685566
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="fetchPendingVideo",repository="VideoRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 219.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="fetchPendingVideo",repository="VideoRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 19.043448373
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="fetchFailVideo",repository="VideoRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 219.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="fetchFailVideo",repository="VideoRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 18.100398981
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="DetectionRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 42.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="DetectionRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.122182027
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="PersonnelRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 6.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="PersonnelRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.025513304
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="RoleRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 8.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="RoleRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.077934631
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="TenantDatabaseRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 1536.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="TenantDatabaseRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 2.028462339
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="latestAlarmsOf20",repository="EventRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 10.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="latestAlarmsOf20",repository="EventRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 1.172652081
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="TagRecordRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 1.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="TagRecordRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.019695152
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="EquipmentRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 1323.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="EquipmentRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 10.013879308
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="findAllByPageable",repository="SubscribeRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 6.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="findAllByPageable",repository="SubscribeRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.1664564
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="findById",repository="EquipmentRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 1.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="findById",repository="EquipmentRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.001886802
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="updateLocation",repository="EquipmentRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 3.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="updateLocation",repository="EquipmentRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.006088206
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="ElectronRegionRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 27.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="ElectronRegionRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.129855111
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="MenuRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 9.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="MenuRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.036770057
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="UserRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 6.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="UserRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.066419261
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="findByUsername",repository="UserRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 39.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="findByUsername",repository="UserRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.347316215
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="findWithFloor",repository="EquipmentRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 27.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="findWithFloor",repository="EquipmentRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.097442355
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="LabEquipmentTrackCoordinateRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 20.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="LabEquipmentTrackCoordinateRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.042921816
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="TrackCoordinateRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 3.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="TrackCoordinateRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.007362144
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="save",repository="EquipmentRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 2.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="save",repository="EquipmentRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.026112679
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="findById",repository="TenantRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 253.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="findById",repository="TenantRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.370145375
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="save",repository="EquipmentDeployRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 1.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="save",repository="EquipmentDeployRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.005853591
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="findById",repository="RoleRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 1.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="findById",repository="RoleRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.003502211
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="findByAreaId",repository="EquipmentRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 1.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="findByAreaId",repository="EquipmentRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.011679715
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="save",repository="DetectionRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 1.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="save",repository="DetectionRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.005231945
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="AreaRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 16.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="AreaRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.045452902
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="LabEquipmentRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 2.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="findAll",repository="LabEquipmentRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.008209858
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="findByType",repository="DetectionRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 13.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="findByType",repository="DetectionRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.036184464
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="findByRoleId",repository="UserRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 1.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="findByRoleId",repository="UserRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.003072213
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="save",repository="RoleRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 1.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="save",repository="RoleRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.008003724
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="deleteById",repository="PersonnelRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 1.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="deleteById",repository="PersonnelRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.018216374
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="findByIsPauseIsFalse",repository="QuartzJobRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 1.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="findByIsPauseIsFalse",repository="QuartzJobRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.030612346
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="save",repository="LogRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 144.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="save",repository="LogRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.488825666
  # HELP executor_pool_core_threads The core number of threads for the pool
 

Then I used another service to expose the API, return this data, and provide Prometheus to collect this data, but no errors were prompted. Is it because the data format is incorrect, or are there other possible reasons?
